# Need help generating static pages in nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, next.js13

I am working with Nextjs 13 building a news app that fetches data from a GNews api. On the home page I have successfully rendered the title and date.

Here is the getData function I am importing into the home page.

```
 export async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch(`https://gnews.io/api/v4/top-headlines?country=us&category=general&limit=10&token=${process.env.GNEWS_API}`, {  next: { revalidate: 43000 } })
  
    const data = await res.json();
    return data.articles
  }
```

Here is the Home page:

```
import slugify from "slugify";
import Link from "next/link";
import { getData } from "@/lib/getData";



export default async function Home() {
    const articles = await getData();

    return articles.map((article: any) => {
      const slug = slugify(article.title, {lower: true})

      return (
      <div key={article.url} className="mb-2">
        <Link href={`/articles/${slug}`}>
        <h2 className="text-xl text-blue-600 underline">{article.title}</h2>
        <p>{article.publishedAt}</p>
        </Link>
      </div>
      )
    })
  }
```

**Note that I had to use slugify to generate an article slug because GNews does not return one.**

I now want to generate the entire article using this path:
articles/[slug]/page.tsx

I am unclear on how to build the entire article on the [slug]/page.tsx file with the title, image, article content etc. I understand I need to use generateStaticParams so nextjs understands what pages to generate at build time. Here is my current code.

```
import { getData } from '@/lib/getData'
import slugify from 'slugify';

export const generateStaticParams = async () => {
const articles = await getData();
return articles.map((article: any) => ({
  slug: slugify(article.title)
}))
}

export default function Article() {

  return (
    <div>page</div>
  )
}
```

Any help with the code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
import { getData } from '@/lib/getData'
import slugify from 'slugify';

export const generateStaticParams = async () => {
    const articles = await getData();

    return articles.map((article: any) => ({
        slug: slugify(article.title)
    }))
}

export default function Article({ params }) { // <- using params
  const { slug } = params; // do something

  return (
    <div>page</div>
  )
}
```

You can also specify additional fields ( img urls, description etc )

```
export const generateStaticParams = async () => {
    const articles = await getData();

    return articles.map((article: any) => ({
        slug: slugify(article.title),
        title: article.title,
        content: article.content,
        // ...
    }))
}

export default function Article({ params }) {
  const { slug, content, title } = params; // do something
  // ...
}
```

More information you can find [here](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/generate-static-params)

Comment: That was helpful. I was having trouble understanding the docs. I am still having issues rendering each article. in the Article component. Can you take it a step further and show me the correct structure. Do I need to map the articles again? If so, what do I pass in since I've already passed params. 


`export default function Article({params}: any) {
const {title, content, slug} = params;
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <p>{content}</p>
    </div>
  )
}`

Comment: Hello! You only need to map articles once in the generateStaticParams function. Each array elem is returned as a param on the next page. I mean for example you have 12 elements in the returned array and you will have 12 different pages with separate params. In docs describing the idea https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/generate-static-params#single-dynamic-segment

Comment: then you can do whatever you want with these params

Comment: Also this article might be helpful
https://www.js-craft.io/blog/example-of-using-the-generatestaticparams-in-nextjs-13-within-the-app-folder/

And this one 
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/44641

Comment: The article is helpful and I following your example, but the article content and title does not display on the page when I click on one of the article links on the home page.
Here is my code. What have I left out? [code](https://github.com/KentHefley/news-api)